# Class members in Backbone/Parse using each other

Tags: javascript, class, backbone.js

```
var User = Parse.User.extend({
    // instance members
}, {
    // types
    TYPE_TRAINER : 1,
    TYPE_ATHLETE : 2,
    types: {
        TYPE_TRAINER : 'Trainer',
        TYPE_ATHLETE : 'Athlete'
    }
});
```

I want to have `TYPE_TRAINER` and `TYPE_ATHLETE` maintain the values of `1` and `2` as defined prior to the `types` object so that I can use the `types` object in a template.

If you don't know about Parse, `Parse.User` is an extension of `Backbone.Model`.

Thanks!

Comment: `types` is not an array as I can see from here

Comment: thanks. i've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is not directly possible in JavaScript object literals. Object literals are always a literal value on the left hand / key side.

The closest you could get is to use the `TYPE_TRAINER` and `TYPE_ATHLETE` keys as variables to assign values via the square bracket syntax for accessing object key/value pairs:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

var obj = {};
obj[a] = "a";
obj[b] = "b";
```

This will result in the `obj` object looking like this:

```
{
  1: "a",
  2: "b"
}
```

So you could do something like this, to get what you want in your code:

```
var userMethods = {
    // types
    TYPE_TRAINER : 1,
    TYPE_ATHLETE : 2
};

userMethods[userMethods.TYPE_TRAINER] = 'Trainer';
userMethods[userMethods.TYPE_ATHLETE] = 'Athlete';

var User = Parse.User.extend({
    // instance members
}, userMethods);
```

It's more code than you probably want, but it's the only way to achieve what you want because of the object literal syntax.

Comment: One of the few downfalls I've seen coming from PHP. The next one is Asynchronous Module Loading - no longer can I rely on PHP's _autoload :( Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The [Parse.Object Javascript documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.extend) says:

You should call either:

```
var MyClass = Parse.Object.extend("MyClass", {
    // Instance properties
}, {
    // Class properties
});
```

or, for Backbone compatibility:

```
var MyClass = Parse.Object.extend({
    className: "MyClass",
    // Other instance properties
}, {
    // Class properties
});
```

If you are wanting to extend the `Parse.User` "class" (it's an object, not a class), you need to include the `className` as described above because `Parse.User` is itself an extension of `Parse.Object`.

Comment: I emailed one of the Parse developers regarding that, and was told to extend the Parse.User object in order to override default functionality to my liking (for example, for Backbone-style validation on the object before saving). I also think you missed the point of the question.